# How do I get notice of a Monero reorg and the transactions that were dropped/modified in those blocks?

Tags: monerod, blockchain

In monerod, I see an example printout:

`BLOCK ADDED AS ALTERNATIVE ON HEIGHT ##########`

What is a recommended way to send information about this reorg to another program?

The main use-case is detecting which transactions were impacted, so that they can be adjusted accordingly. Most importantly, I need to know if a transaction has been dropped or modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a recommended way to send information about this reorg to another program?
>
> The main use-case is detecting which transactions were impacted...

If you start `monerod` with `--reorg-notify`, it will execute the supplied script / program each time a reorg occurs.

You can then call the daemon RPC [/get_transaction_pool](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transaction_pool) looking for transactions where `kept_by_block` is true.